# javascript - get Object based on property's value

Tags: javascript, jquery

... if I have the following constructor and then create an instance of the class:

```
    /* Gallery */
function Gallery( _horseName ){
    this.horseName = _horseName
    this.pixList = new Array();
}

var touchGallery = new Gallery( "touch" )
```

... how can I get the Gallery object based on the value of horseName?

Thought about implementing something like:

```
Gallery.prototype.getGalleryByHorseName = function( _horseName ){ /* to be implemented */}
```

... but got stuck on that. Is there a cleaner or canonical way to accomplish this? Eventually I'll have to access that Gallery object in jQuery as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't. The gallery doesnt have a list of all instances.

Comment: ... hm, put it in a Map of key:value pairs? Where key would would be the gallery name and value the Galley object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest solution is to keep your created objects in an object.

```
var myGalleries = {};

myGalleries['touchA'] = new Gallery( "touchA" );
myGalleries['touchB'] = new Gallery( "touchB" );
```

Then you can quickly access them by passing a key.

```
var galleryOfTouchB = myGalleries['touchB'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this. I think it's fairly clean and canonical:

```
var Galleries = (function() {
    var all = [],
        galleriesObj = {};

    galleriesObj.create = function(horseName) {
        var gallery = {
            horseName: horseName,
            pixList: []
        };
        all.push(gallery);
        return gallery;
    };

    galleriesObj.find = function(horseName) {
        var ii;
        for (ii = 0; ii < all.length; ii += 1) {
            if (all[ii].horseName === horseName) {
                return all[ii];
            }
        }
        return null;
    };

    return galleriesObj;
}());

var touchGallery = Galleries.create('touch');

var foundGallery = Galleries.find('touch');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in a nice oo way, by writing a class which holds a list to all Gallery instances and then write a function iterating over each Gallery object and returning the one with the matching name.

Supaweu shows a very nice and easy (non-oo) example

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a step or two. You need an array of Gallery objects, and then iterate through the array while checking the _horseName property.

Answer (score -1):

You could go at it by creating an object filled with horse name galleries that havve been created:

```
/* Gallery */
function Gallery( _horseName ){
    this.horseName = _horseName
    this.pixList = new Array();
    Gallery.galleryList[_horseName] = this; // Add this gallery to the list
}
Gallery.galleryList = {};

var touchGallery = new Gallery( "touch" )
var galleryByName = Gallery.galleryList["touch"];
```

Comment: Thats not how the prototype works. Functions in the prototype are _shared_ by all instances

Comment: That is what I meant, but it probably came out wrong.
I meant that by using prototype he wouldn't achieve what he wanted, because then he'll share a function with all instances that isn't meant to be used by instances.